# JS files not being loaded properly

Tags: javascript

The problem I am facing is that I do not think the files `rules.js` and `actions.js` *(which are in the `categories` folder)* are loaded in properly.

**index.html:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="categories/rules.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="categories/actions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="quando_blocks.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="quando_editor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

**quando_editor:**

```
var quando_blocks = this["quando_blocks"];
```

In `quando_editor.js` *(or any file that's on the same level as `index.html`)*, `this["**filename**"]` can be used to save the file to a variable. You will then be able to call functions within that file.

When trying to do the same thing for `rule.js` *(`this["rules"]`)*, it returned `undefined` *(and I presume the same will be for `actions`)*. Logging out `this`, I can see that the files `quando_blocks` and `quando_editor` are loaded in properly but not `rules` or `actions`.

[image]

Inspecting the network in DevTools, I can see that `rules.js` and `actions.js` are actually loaded in, just when I refer to them using `this`, they're not there.

Also `index.js` is also loaded in fine.

This is my file structure

```
editor
 |
 +- categories
    |
    +- rules.js
    +- action.js
 |
 +- js
    |
    +- index.js
 |
 +- index.html
 +- quando_blocks.js
 +- quando_editor.js
```

**Note:**

- The level the files are at doesn't seem to make a difference
- The order of the `<script>` tags also doesn't make a difference
- I have also tried `this["categories/rules"]` which also returns `undefined`

**UPDATE:**

I can now see my `rules` and `actions` objects in the window object:

[image]

HOWEVER, when trying to access methods on those objects, it throws:

> Cannot read property 'addBlocks' of undefined

I thought I has fixed it but obviously not...

**quando_blocks.js** *(the relevant parts)*:

```
(() => {
    let self = this["quando_blocks"] = {};

    let rules = this["rules"];
    let actions = this["actions"];
    let ropedClimbing = this["ropedClimbing"];

    self.addBlocks = (quando_editor) => {
        rules.addBlocks(quando_editor);
        actions.addBlocks(quando_editor);
        ropedClimbing.addBlocks(quando_editor);
    }
})();
```

**rules.js** *(the relevant parts)*:

```
(() => {
    let self = this["rules"] = {};

    self.addBlocks = (quando_editor) => {
        ...
    };
})();
```

Comment: The source URLs for imported JavaScript don't have any effect on how the code is evaluated in the browser.

Comment: Also `var quando_blocks = this["quando_blocks"];` is not doing anything like "saving the file to a variable".

Comment: @Pointy can you please explain? What is that lien doing then?

Comment: @wmash The keyword `this` refers to an object context or window global object. So, `this["quando_blocks"]` does absolutly nothing. If you are inside a class/object and uses `this["quando_blocks"]` it only will return the value of the variable `quando_blocks`. So, I didn't understand how you want "save a file into a variable" with that expression.

Comment: @wmash In your context this refers to window object. It has all those properties what your scripts add to global space.

Comment: The situation in which `quando_blocks` would end up as a global symbol with a value would be when somewhere in the HTML document there is an element with id "quando_blocks".

Comment: @Pointy there is no element within the HTML that as the id `"quando_blocks"`. I understand what `this` does usually when inside a normal object/class but inside a window object I am not so sure. As @Ninja mentioned, `this` should have the properties that my scripts load into the global space. Which is what I am confused on as `rules.js` and `actions.js` are loaded in but cannot be referred to with the window object

Comment: Well it might be easier to help if you'd post the actual code. The `<script>` elements themselves really don't provide any clues whatsoever.

Comment: There's nothing that automatically turns script names into properties of the `window` object. There's no reason to expect `this["rules"]` to work.

Comment: @Pointy while amending my question, I realised my error. I will post an answer soon but may be too localised for anyone else to deem useful

Comment: @Pointy I have added an update. Can you please read and have a look

Comment: @Pointy again, this has now been solved. The order of the `<script>` tags was wrong

Comment: OK good, because I really couldn't figure out what exactly your code was trying to do :)